# How can I replace deprecated method Mockit.setUpMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

I have some code, which is using old version of jmockit library. I find out that setUpMock method of Mockit class is deprecated, but I cann't find on Jmockit API documentation explanation, how can I replace code like below.

```
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void updateWithBadRownum() throws Exception
{
    Mockit.setUpMock(Tool.class, new MockTool()); //It doesn't support on latest version of jmockit
    Mockit.setUpMock(Criteria.class, new MockCriteria());
    new TaskInitializer().populateSchemas(cnn, 10);
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("ROWNUM", "abc");
    Assert.assertTrue(4 == StatusUpdaterImpl.execute(parameters));
}
```

Comment: The API documentation for version 1.1 (and others) does say (in the deprecation comments of the old API and in the documentation for the new API) how to replace uses of `Mockit.setUpMock`, etc. with the new API (`MockUp`).

Comment: Could you provide me link, please? I didn't find comments

Comment: Sure. The release notes for versions [1.1](http://jmockit.org/changes.html#1.1), [1.2](http://jmockit.org/changes.html#1.2), [1.3](http://jmockit.org/changes.html#1.3), [1.4](http://jmockit.org/changes.html#1.4), and [1.5](http://jmockit.org/changes.html#1.5) all talk about the removal of old API and the corresponding new API to be used. The deprecation comments in the API documentation for version 1.1 can be found in the `jmockit-1.1-sources.jar` file, available from [Maven Central](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/googlecode/jmockit/jmockit/1.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Mockup](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/MockUp.html)

```
new MockUp<Tool>() {
    @Mock int someMethod(int i) { assertTrue(i > 0); return 123; }

 };
```